# SharePoint Workflow Fails to Start BUT It Works 90% of the Time Otherwise - So Frustrated :(

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow that's a chain of If/Else statements. If a certain option is selected from the dropdown item, it emails x team. Else if another option is selected from the dropdown item, it emails y team. Etc.

The workflow is setup to send an email on creation or on change.

The workflow works 90% of the time. Then suddenly it just stops working for no apparent reason. It almost feels like it stops working for a period of time and then starts again. I am banging my head against the wall because I can't recreate the issue no matter how hard I try. When I see the "Failed to Start" error, I can most of the time just go back into the item, resubmit, then the workflow works again even without changing a thing. Sometimes it still fails then I just keep trying to resubmit the item until the workflow just works again.

I've googled for two days straight, and I've given up. I need some help desperately. Can anyone help me figure this out? Is it my Workflow code?
[image: Workflow]

I've tried adding pauses at the top of the workflow, that didn't help. I tried scaling it down to removing all if/else statements and just sending an email no matter what, and it still failed periodically. I added the "Update Current Item" lines and that somehow seemed to make it work for a while and then it stopped again. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I would ask IT to check the SharePoint error logs for the failed to start issue. But also, I'd add a log step as the first action to log the value of contract request. (Your screen shot starts with an else-if. Is there anything else in the workflow besides the if statement above that?)

Comment: It starts with an If statement (I couldn't fit the whole image in my screen grab lol). I've reached out to IT to see if there's something they can do but with the holidays it'll probably be another week before anyone chimes in. Hopefully it's something they can fix. I'll update as soon as I hear more. Thanks for the reply!